# Collective Influence Algorithm in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, networking, nodes, edges

Hello everyone, I need help to implement an algorithm for the collective influence model [CI=(Ki - 1) * sum(Kj -1)] in Matlab. This model computes the Collective Influence values of each node on a network. It is given by the product of the degrees of node i less 1 and the sum of the degrees of the next nearest neighbours of node i less 1 as specified by distance d. ‘d’ can be from 2-hop, 3-hop or more hops from node i.

The idea is to determine the nodes with the most influence on a network that are capable of collapsing or totally fragmenting the network when they are removed. After the first iteration, the CI value is calculated and sorted in descending order. The node with the highest CI value is removed and the calculation is repeated and CI sorted again to determine the node with the next highest CI value. The cycle continues until the network is completely fragmented with the least number of largest components.

So far, I have tried to implement this model using Matlab inbuilt syntaxes. I can access the next nearest neighbours of node i but when I calculate its degree values, it includes the direct neighbours of node i and node i as well.   See the code below:

[Image of the sample network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgIjk.jpg)

```
for i=1:gg
    Neb = neighbors(G,i); %Calculates the neighbours of node i
    degNodi=degree(G,i);  %Calculates the degree of node i
    d=distances(G);       %Calculates distances of all nodes from each pivot
                          %note
    for m=1:length(Neb)   %Calculates the length of of node i's neighbours 
                          %at each iteration                         
        NNN=neighbors(G,Neb(m));  %Finds the neighbours of the neighbours of 
                                  %node i or next nearest neighbours        
        if NNN==Neb(m) || NNN==G(i)
           NNN=find(NNN~=Neb) & find(NNN~=G(i));
        end
        Kj=degree(G,NNN);         %Calculates the degrees of the next 
                                  %nearest neighbours of node i
    end
end
```

My challenge with the above code is to access and compute the degree values of node i’s 2-hop or more hop neighbours excluding direct neihbours of node i and node i.

Q: Which line of code can I use to get rid of direct neighbours of node i and node i after I calculate the degree values of node i's 2-hop neighbours?

I also tried another code but I have not been able to get the result I need.

```
load('simp10net.mat');
networkA=A;
N=size(networkA,1);
mmm=0;
for i=1:N
  neb1=length(kmin_neighbors(networkA,i,1));
  neb2=kmin_neighbors(networkA,i,2);
  m=length(neb2); 
     for m1=1:m
         for q=1:m
             NN(find(networkA(neb2(m),m1)))=1;
         end
     end
   mmm=NN-1;
   Kjall=sum(mmm);
   collInf(i)=((neb1 - 1)* Kjall);
end
```

In the above code, I was able to access the 2-hop neighbours of node i but I don’t know the correct syntax or line of code that I can use to enable me calculate the degree values. I do not get the expected result after I run it.

Which line of code can help me do this?

Q: How can I retain the identities/tags of each node since after removing the node with the highest CI value at each iteration, the network is less a node and the numbering changes?

Any help or advice on how to make this code more efficient will be so much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried computing the [`distances`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html) of each pair of nodes in the graph? If you assume edge weights of 1, the distance between nodes is equal to the  number of hops.

Comment: Please add all updates to the question itself using the [edit] link. Please also format your post (especially code) correctly. See [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for examples.

Comment: Hello @beaker thanks for pointing out the corrections. I have re-formatted the codes and edited the questions. When I run the code, I don't the expected results. In the distances you suggested, if i should use it then, I have to specify manually the sources and the targets. But what I need to do is more like assign variables to represent these nodes and it will be done automatically by the code.

Comment: Why would you have to manually specify the sources and targets? The first function signature in the documentation is `d = distances(G)` which computes the distances between all pairs of nodes in the graph. If you have this (again, assuming that the graph is unweighted or all edge weights are 1), then you have the number of hops between every pair of nodes and can select whatever hop count you want.

Comment: As for your code, I don't know what `kmin_neighbors` is, so I can't execute it, or even trace the execution manually to find where the problem might be. "I do not get the expected result" is not a very precise problem description, so I don't have anything to go on there. The degree of each node follows from the adjacency matrix. It's the number of nonzero elements in the row (or column) for that node (assuming a symmetric matrix).

Comment: @beaker kmin_neighbors is actually a tool which returns the neighbours of node i as specified by desirable distance from node i. Using it, I have been able to access the 2-hop neighbours of node i but then I have not been able to calculate their degree values.

Comment: @beaker I tried to use the distances syntax but it does not actually give me what I need. Meanwhile, I executed this syntax NNN=neighbors(G,Neb(m)); and I have been able to access the next nearest neighbours of node i. But then, if I calculate its degree, it includes both the neighbours of node i and node i which should not be part of the set of nodes targeted at that point. How do I get rid of them? For eg, on the picture I attached, node 10 has nodes 5, 8 and 9 as its neighbours and nodes 2, 3 , 6 and 7 as its next nearest neighbours. How do I calculate the degrees of nodes 2, 3, 6 and 7?